# how to use pacpl in nemo

Tags: nemo

I'm using Nemo File Manager, and for working purpose I need to have the pacpl audio converter installed in it. There's no way I can have it. Is there anyone that can provide a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Nemo, you can create your own Action scripts (scripts that appear in the context menu for certain files). You can find a well documented example script [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action).

With the help provided there, it should be easy to create your own sction script, which you can then save in `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/your_action.nemo_action`.

As an example, I'm using the following script to update the modification timestamp (mtime) by invoking `touch` on the target file(s):

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Touch
Comment=Update Last Change Timestamp
Icon-Name=time
Exec=/usr/bin/touch %F
Selection=notnone
Extensions=any
EscapeSpaces=true
```

With the help of pacpl's [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/pacpl.1.html), it shouldn't be too hard to create an action script for audio conversion.

Comment: the_Seppi, Thanks for your time and suggestion. Best, Martin